# Quality check robot

Tags: microcontroller

How to develop a robot based system to continuously monitor and check products for defeat which are moving on a conveyer belt using sensors and kick out the defect product from the queue?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Rishabh, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem, so questions that ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you have more concrete problems and actually say what your parameters, constraints etc. are, we are glad to help. I'd suggest reading on image processing (edge detection etc.), [sensors in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sensors) and electric motors to get an overview.